# Rails: Ensure password is present if password_confirmation is given

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I'm working through the [Ruby on Rails Tutorial](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/) and in the [exercises for 10.1.2 - Unsuccessful Edits](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/updating_and_deleting_users#sec-exercises_unssuccessful_edits) I'm being asked to test that the application correctly catches invalid form submissions.

Perhaps I did the exercise too thoroughly - I've found that it's "valid" to submit a `nil` password with a non-`nil` password_confirmation.

I thought that `has_secure_password` would catch this?

1) Why doesn't it?

2) How do I ensure that if `password` is equal to `password_confirmation`?

I currently have:
`validates :password, presence: true, length: { minimum: 6 }, allow_nil: true`

I've tried adding `, confirmation: true`, but this doesn't help.

Comment: Try removing allow_nil: true

Comment: `nil` is required for the profile edit page - a user shouldn't be required to enter a password & confirmation if they just want to edit a profile setting.

Comment: Update will be triggered only on attributes which you change I think. Give it try if u haven't already.

Comment: Nope - my 'successful edit' test fails if I remove `allow_nil: true`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `validates` which only applies based upon a boolean:

```
validates :password, presence: true, if: :password_confirmation_given?

def password_confirmation_given?
  password_confirmation.nil? ? false : !password_confirmation.empty?
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want devise to do validations you can add the validatable module to your model.

```
devise
  :validatable
```

If you want rails to validate it you can use

```
validates_confirmation_of :password
```

If you are still having issues check how you are initializing strong parameters and/or post your params code.